# EXT4 Mount gives this error "SELinux: mount invalid. Same superblock, different security settings"

Tags: storage, mount, partitions, app2sd, link2sd

I am trying to `mount` a second `partition  (ext4 )` for my apps ( I guess its a bit outdated with adoptable storage but then `ext4` isn't accepted FS for adoption for external card ) . I am on `9.0 ( Pie )` and all my SD `partitions` are mounted under `/storage` and some weird name .e.g.

```
/storage/ 6226b27a-ebc1-4fdd-b54c-096abc40c2b9
```

Now I need my 2nd `Partition` to be mounted under `/data/sdext2` but O.S already mounts it. 
`app2sd ( link2sd)` gives me `Mount script` argument invalid argument . No matter what .

On digging further through OS logs I get this info

```
[   48.820728] EXT4-fs (mmcblk1p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: nomblk_io_submit,errors=remount-ro
[   48.941276] EXT4-fs (mmcblk1p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:
[   48.969786] sdcardfs: mounted on top of /mnt/media_rw/6226b27a-ebc1-4fdd-b54c-096abc40c2b9 type ext4
[   48.970918] Remount options were mask=18,gid=9997 for vfsmnt ffffffda2f7539e0.
[   48.971668] Remount options were mask=18,gid=9997 for vfsmnt ffffffda95617660.
```

......

```
[  107.476736] SELinux: mount invalid.  Same superblock, different security settings for (dev mmcblk1p2, type ext4)
```

**What I did :**
`Umount` partition as `mount master` under `Terminal Emulator`. Its umounted only in context but not everywhere. But in-spite of `umount` I cant seem to mount it under `/data/sdext2`

Whats happening  and how to work around .

On a side note. How do I manually assign `mount point` names  and prevent these weird names given by OS to the `partitions`
and on a 'side side' note. I am not even sure if this is the reason for invalid mount error as I read elsewhere its more of a benign FYI message.

Comment: you can handle it two ways: 1) umount /dev/block/mmcblk1p2 (with busybox) before mounting /data/sdext2. or 2) bind mount /mnt/media_rw/6226b27a-ebc1-4fdd-b54c-096abc40c2b9 to /data/sdext2

Comment: Weird name is filesystem UUID, that's how Android uniquely identity external SD cards and USB drives. And as Portable Storage, external SD card is mounted under `/mnt/media_rw/`, apps just see it under `/storage/` through Storage Access Framework (SAF). Nothing else I get from your question what you want to achieve.

Comment: `[  107.476736] SELinux: mount invalid.  Same superblock, different security settings for (dev mmcblk1p2, type ext4)
` this☝️ error... why do i get it and what is the fix Thank You for responding

Comment: that was long time ago, i did some tweaking Which I can't remember now but i don't see it now. But not sure what caused.it